# How to update text box based on combo box value

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

Beginner on Using MS access 2016 and VBA. I am trying to show information on how many items have been reserved or is in the reserve table based on what the user selects as the tool.

The tool combo box(cmbo_Tool) selects a tool from Table A. I need to count the amount of times this tool appears in Table B and then display it in textBox A.

I have made a query involving both tables, but i'm unsure on how to apply it to the label.

Instead I have used the AfterUpdate event on cmbo_tool and using the DCount option.

Another way I thought about is taking the Tool Id (in this case, say 5) from Table A, and searching for it in a column table B, and counting.

'using `Dcount`'

```vb
Private Sub cmbo_Tool_AfterUpdate()

  Me.Text1404 = DCount("cmbo_Tool", "tbl_Booking", "Tool")

End Sub
```

'Using Table id'

```vb
Private Sub cmbo_Tool_AfterUpdate()

 Dim T_var as integer

 Dim FinalOut as integer

  T_var = Me.cmbo_Tool.Column(0)   'This gives 5'

  'I need to make T_Var link to Table b and count'

  Me.Text1404 = FinalOut

End Sub
```

Using Dcount method, it gives a number im unsure of. I'm not even sure if im using dcount correctly.

Using the table id method, Im unsure how to take the value 5 and count it in table B, then display in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it could be something like this:

```vb
Private Sub cmbo_Tool_AfterUpdate()

  Me!Text1404.Value = DCount("*", "tbl_Booking", "Tool = " & cmbo_Tool & "")

  ' If Tool is text, then use quotes:
  ' Me!Text1404.Value = DCount("*", "tbl_Booking", "Tool = '" & cmbo_Tool & "'")

End Sub
```

And do *rename* your controls to something meaningful.